# Exract all int64 elements from array Bigquery

Tags: arrays, google-bigquery

I would like to extract all elements from array, not only top one.
The code I used:

```
SELECT listings_impression, flattened
FROM `data_marts.mixpanel_raw_data`
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(listings_impression) as flattened
limit 10
```

The result is on attached screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below instead

```
SELECT flattened
FROM `data_marts.mixpanel_raw_data`
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(listings_impression) as flattened
limit 10
```

Comment: thank you! I tried to filter on one of the elements which were not on the top and seems it's working

Comment: great. consider also voting up the answer! :o)